# How to convert array of model objects to object with model ids as keys?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, redux, map-function

In Javascript I have an array of model objects:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":13,
      "title":"Some title 1",
      "time": "friday"
      ...
   },
   {  
      "id":15,
      "title":"Some title 3",
      "time": "Saturday"
      ...
   },
   {  
      "id":16,
      ...
   },
   ...
]
```

(there is more than 2 values and properties on each object)
I want to get an object with each id from the array moved to key, like so:

```
{
  13: {
    title: "Some title 1",
    time: "Friday"
    ...
  },
  15: {
    title: "Some title 3",
    time: "Saturday"
    ...
  },
  16: {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I am producing the array with Rails view `.to_json include: {}` syntax, so an answer in rails would also work for me. I will use the result object with Redux for an initial state so some kind of Redux answer is great too. Also would be interested in both es6 and es5 answer (I will use es5 answer though because Rails doesn't compile es6 in views, but later we are porting to client side application where it would also apply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to iterate over the array and attach a copy of each item to a new object:

```
let result = {};
for (let item of data) {
  let newObject = Object.assign({}, item);
  result[newObject.id] = newObject;
  delete newObject.id;
}
```

If you don't need the data array later on it gets even simpler:

```
let result = {};
for (let item of data) {
  result[item.id] = item;
  delete item.id;
}
```

Comment: I would be very interested in a reason for voting down a working solution.

Comment: @Aurimas I appreciate your appreciation.

Comment: Would be nice to have it as a function, so I could just say `new_items = convert(items)`

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to just iterate through the array in Ruby:

```
foo = [  
   {  
      "id":13,
      "title":"Some title 1",
      ...
   },
   {  
      "id":15,
      "title":"Some title 3",
      ...
   }]

result = {}
foo.each {|f| result[f.delete('id')] = f}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to create object and inside you can loop object properties with `Object.keys()` and `forEach()` loop to create inner objects.

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 13,
  "title": "Some title 1",
  'lorem': 'ipsum'
}, {
  "id": 15,
  "title": "Some title 3",
}, {
  "id": 16,
}]

var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e.id] = {}
  Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k) {
    if(k != 'id') r[e.id] = Object.assign(r[e.id], {[k]: e[k]})
  })
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Another approach is to use `reduce()` two times. First one to create one outer object and inner reduce to create each object inside first object.

```js
var data = [{"id":13,"title":"Some title 1","lorem":"ipsum"},{"id":15,"title":"Some title 3"},{"id":16}]

var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e.id] = Object.keys(e).reduce(function(o, a) {
   if(a != 'id') o[a] = e[a]
    return o;
  }, {})
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, trying it out!

Comment: @Aurimas Please take a look at update. You need to create object out of foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
return users.reduce((results, u)=> (results[u.id] = u, results), {})
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
try {
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray("yourJsonString");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){


                JSONObject outer_jsonObject=new JSONObject();
                JSONObject inner_jsonObject=new JSONObject();

                inner_jsonObject.put("title",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                outer_jsonObject.put(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),inner_jsonObject);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for confusion, I didn't write that this is Javascript question. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you following approach.

For every `id`, assign an object with `titles` key, holding an array of titles as it's value.

It looks clean and it's easily readable, especially when there's few titles for one `id`.

```js
var arr=[{id:13,title:"Some title 1"},{id:15,title1:"Some title 3",title2:"Some title 4"},{id:16}],     result = [];

arr.forEach(function(v){
  var obj = {};
  var titles = {};
  var titlesArr = [];
  Object.keys(v).forEach(function(c){
    if (c != 'id') {
      titlesArr.push(v[c]);
      titles.titles = titlesArr;
    }
  });
  obj.id = titles;
  result.push(obj);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. Kind of blew my mind, have to think about possible uses of this kind of object. Are you thinking only if there is `id` and `title` properties? The three dots in my question code mean there are more..

Comment: @Aurimas Yeah, I thought the same because of these dots. That's why I've made this solution for you. Do you want me to describe each step?

Comment: If I want to render one of those (sub)objects to a modal for example, how is this structure helpful? Speaking of Redux/Reat stack here

Comment: @Aurimas Unfortunately I'm not in Redux/React, but this solution is imo more tidy and clean, because you can store as many titles as you want, inside the titles array. There's no need to make x keys with title values. It's just my opinion, you can use if you like it.